# How to get controller value in Action filter in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing Audit functionality in Web API using below code :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetList()
    {
        //var dd = ((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId").Value;

        AuditBAL auditBAL = new AuditBAL();

        Audit audit = new Audit();
        audit.TableName = TableName.Terms_TABLE;
        audit.MenuId = Convert.ToInt64(PageEnum.Terms);
        audit.ActionId = Convert.ToInt64(ActionEnum.List);
        audit.UserId = Convert.ToInt64(((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId").Value);

        auditBAL.Save(audit);

        return Ok(new ResponceView<DataTable>()
        {
            ResponseObject = termBAL.GetList()
        });
    }
```

Using Above method I can audit all events but I have to write above code audit code for all Controllers methods.

I want to it to be common for all methods So I am using Action Filter in Web API but I do not know How to get pass Audit object in Action Filter Or How to get method name and Controller name in Action Filter. Once I will get necessary information in Action Filter I can use those information to do Audit.

same thing I want to do for Exception filter (want to get Method name and controller name in Exception Filter).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

---

> How to get method name and Controller name in Action Filter and
>   Exception Filter

---

```
   public class ActionDetailAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //context.ActionContext
            var actionName = ((System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor).ActionName;
            var controllerName = context.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }

    public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            //context.ActionContext
            var actionName = ((System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor).ActionName;
            var controllerName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your decision about using ActionFilter is good. The thing is to decide where to put the audit call, before (OnActionExecuting) or after(OnActionExecuted) action name is called. That is a technical decision you have to make based on needs.

**Filter Class:**

```
    public class AuditFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var controllerName = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var auditRepository = SvcLocator.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>();
            auditRepository.SaveAudit(controllerName, actionName);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            var controllerName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var actionName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var auditRepository = SvcLocator.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>();
            auditRepository.SaveAudit(controllerName, actionName);
        }
    }
```

Consider create a new component where audit object creation will be done. Keep a clean code in filter class.
Also and more important, you can refactor the code since the code inside two methods are similar.

**Controller:**

```
 [AuditFilter]
 public class ChatroomController : ApiController
 {...
```

**New Component:**

```
  public class AuditRepository : IAuditRepository
  {
      public void SaveAudit(string controllerName, string actionName)
      {
          var auditEntity = new AuditEntity()
            {
                TableName = "Customer",
                ManuId = "Shopping",
                ControllerId = controllerName,
                ActionId = actionName
            };

            //Save into database here
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:**

- Since you need the audit in all actions for all controllers, the attribute must be placed at controller level so all actions will perform the filter
- Running base.OnActionExecuted does not make any sense here since there is no default implementation in the netframework.